# "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" error in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am getting an invalid foreign key error in my controller's create method:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in TytsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
app/controllers/tyts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

I checked my associations and controller and think they are set up properly:

```
class TytsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if current_user.type == 'Student'
      @tyt = Tyt.new(tyt_params)
      @tyt.student_id = current_user.id
      @tyt.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

    def tyt_params
        params.permit(
          :student_id,
          :turkish_correct,
          :turkish_incorrect,
          :math_correct,
          .
          .
          .
          :chemistry_incorrect)
      end
  end
```

```
class Student < User
    attr_accessor :teacher_id

    has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :teachers, through: :connections, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "teacher_id"
    has_many :tyts, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "student_id"

end
```

```
class Tyt < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :student

end
```

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_08_01_092656) do

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tyts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "turkish_correct"
    t.integer "turkish_incorrect"
    t.integer "math_correct"
    .
    .
    .
    .
    t.integer "student_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_tyts_on_student_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "tyts", "students"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an object of type `User`(`current_user`) to `student_id`(which has to be `Student`) so therefore you get the foreign key violation.

Comment: + a tip. Never name a column `type`, you will get more trouble out of it than good. Try naming it `user_type` or something in that sense,

Comment: And your DB structure is kind of weird, I think you will need to rethink the model of it. Have a look at this [single table inheritance](https://www.netguru.com/blog/single-table-inheritance-rails). It could be useful for your User/Student case.

Comment: It is fixed by associating exam and user(instead student), also changed the type to user_type as suggested. I thought it is already STI, student and teacher has same structure and login/register so they inherit those from user. Would be glad if you have any improvements for models

Comment: It's not really STI because you have 2 tables for Users and for Students. The name itself says (Single table inheritance). You basically have a single table in which are stored both students and users but you just differentiate them by type. Since this is not in the scope of the question and I don't want to spam this thread with unrelated topics, you can hit me up on my email if you need some tips.